Local Azure Function Deployment
I am very green to Azure functions. But I have managed to deploy a function and have it run Successfully when the output is to be created to the current Directory. No issues up to here everything is fine.
The next thing I like to do is save the output to a specific folder. This causes an Error. I will list error shortly.
What I like to know is once I get this error even if I go back to the code that I have verified works now produces the same error. Yes I made sure I saved file before I ran the func start -verbose command
Ok here is the working code:
#Works NO issues
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import logging
import subprocess
import os

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True, use_monitor=False)
def ScrapyTimerTrigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

    week = 'week'  # Set your desired week
    year = '2023'  # Set your desired year
    game = 'hall-of-fame-weekend'  # Set your desired game
    local_file_name = f'{year}_{week}_{game}.json'
    #local_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), local_file_name)

    scrapy_command = [
        'scrapy', 'crawl', 'NFLWeatherData',
        '-a', f'Week={week}', '-a', f'Year={year}', '-a', f'Game={game}',
        '-o', local_file_name # local_file_path
    ]

    # Update this path to the correct directory
    process = subprocess.Popen(scrapy_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=r"N:\github\SportsData\NFLWeather\FunctionLocal\NFLWeather")
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        logging.error(stderr)
    else:
        logging.info(stdout)

That will produce file with no issue
Here is the modified code to write to an another location
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import logging
import subprocess
import os

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True, 
use_monitor=False)
def ScrapyTimerTrigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

if myTimer.past_due:
    logging.info('The timer is past due!')

logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

week = 'week'  # Set your desired week
year = '2023'  # Set your desired year
game = 'hall-of-fame-weekend'  # Set your desired game
local_file_name = f'{year}_{week}_{game}.json'
local_file_path = os.path.join(r"N:\\github\\SportsData\\NFLWeather\\Data_Gathering", year, local_file_name)

# Create the directory if it does not exist
directory_path = os.path.join(r"N:\\github\\SportsData\\NFLWeather\\Data_Gathering", year)
os.makedirs(directory_path, exist_ok=True)

scrapy_command = [
    'scrapy', 'crawl', 'NFLWeatherData',
    '-a', f'Week={week}', '-a', f'Year={year}', '-a', f'Game={game}',
    '-o', local_file_path
]

# Update this path to the correct directory
process = subprocess.Popen(scrapy_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=r"N:\github\SportsData\NFLWeather\FunctionLocal\NFLWeather")
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if process.returncode != 0:
    logging.error(stderr)
else:
    logging.info(stdout)

Here is the error code that this script produces
    [2024-06-24T00:41:45.459Z] Received WorkerInitRequest, python version 3.11.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Apr 19 2024, 16:40:41) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], worker version 4.28.1, request ID 583ffc8a-a82c-49d4-b586-a0ded194964c. App Settings state: PYTHON_THREADPOOL_THREAD_COUNT: 1000 | PYTHON_ENABLE_WORKER_EXTENSIONS: False. To enable debug level logging, please refer to https://aka.ms/python-enable-debug-logging
[2024-06-24T00:41:45.767Z] Received WorkerMetadataRequest, request ID 583ffc8a-a82c-49d4-b586-a0ded194964c, function_path: N:\github\SportsData\NFLWeather\FunctionLocal\NFLWeather\NFLWeatherFunctionApp\function_app.py
[2024-06-24T00:41:45.797Z] Worker failed to index functions
[2024-06-24T00:41:45.799Z] Result: Failure
Exception: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1269-1270: malformed \N character escape (function_app.py, line 43)
Stack:   File "M:\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 413, in _handle__functions_metadata_request
    self.load_function_metadata(
  File "M:\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 393, in load_function_metadata
    self.index_functions(function_path, function_app_directory)) \
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "M:\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 765, in index_functions
    indexed_functions = loader.index_function_app(function_path)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "M:\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 44, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "M:\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.11\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 238, in index_function_app
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "M:\Miniconda3\envs\Azure\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1074, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1004, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed

Here is what I dont understand an I like to know why or what do I have to do so that the working file works again. Is there some cache or something that has to be cleared in order for the working file to work again. This will allow me to make changes to path location and put something that works
Also these are some of the variations I have tried
 # local_file_path = os.path.join("N:\\github\\SportsData\\NFLWeather\\Data_Gathering\\2024", local_file_name)
 # local_file_path = os.path.join(r"N:\\github\\SportsData\\NFLWeather\\Data_Gathering\\2024", local_file_name)
 # local_file_path = Path("N:/github/SportsData/NFLWeather/Data_Gathering/2024") / local_file_name
 # local_file_path = Path(r"N:\github\SportsData\NFLWeather\Data_Gathering\2024") / local_file_name


The error you're encountering is due to the way you're using the backslashes \ in your file paths in Windows. In Python, the backslash is an escape character, so you need to either escape the backslash i.e., use \ or use raw strings by prefixing the string with r.

Add the path as N:/github/SportsData/NFLWeather/Data_Gathering and try again.

Thanks for the repy. Yes, I have tried that and it propably works but I cant figure out why once it fails there is no way to change script and change the error message, As stated in the original post. Even going back the working script still fails there is something here at play that is not seeing my changes. I would like to know what that is that way I can test your thoery.

Ok found the issue I had both scripts in the Function_app.py file. I had one of the scripts inside triple single quotes '''  code  '''
I was under the impression that it was commented out but thats not the case and it was causing the issue. Both scripts work.  Thank you for your help
